# ProjectionEntityQuery is working but KeyQuery is not, for same used filter and projecting the one filtered value

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have an entity-kind K with an indexed timestamp-field T. I want to query for all entity-keys, such that t<X, where t is the value of T, for some given timestamp-value X. When I do a keys-only-query I get the error:

```
Query timed out. Please try either limiting the entities scanned, or run with an updated index configuration.
```

But, when I do the same query as a projection-query, which also returns the values t of the indexed timestamp-field T, then it works.

I repeated the calls several times. The outcome was always the same.

This is what I do:

```
Timestamp timestampX = Timestamp.of(X); (e.g. X="today at 0:00h")
PropertyFilter filterLt = PropertyFilter.lt("T", timestampX);
```

keys-only-query:

```
KeyQuery keyQuery = Query.newKeyQueryBuilder()
    .setKind("K").setFilter(filterLt).build();
QueryResults<Key> queryResults = datastore.run(keyQuery);
while (queryResults.hasNext()) {
    Key key = queryResults.next();
    //...
}
```

projection-query:

```
ProjectionEntityQuery projectionEntityQuery = Query.newProjectionEntityQueryBuilder()
    .setKind("K").setProjection("T").setFilter(filterLt).build();
QueryResults<ProjectionEntity> queryResults = datastore.run(projectionEntityQuery);
while (queryResults.hasNext()) {
    ProjectionEntity projectionEntity = queryResults.next();
    //...
}
```

Background info: There are 3.3 million entities of the kind K. The values t of the indexed timestamp-field T are closely together, roughly all values are within a range of 6 hours, which means that there are 150 entities per second. I know that this is an anti-pattern. The use-case is simple: "T" is the "lastUpdated"-Timestamp. And I want to update every entity every 24 hours. There are different (parallel) processes to update the entities (which of course change the values t of "T" to the current timestamp). As I can't guarantee that the process, that normally updates the entities, works as intended, there are other processes later in the day, that want to update all entities which weren't updated so far today. Hence I use the query as stated above, to only obtain those entity-keys of entities that need to be updated.

I am using Google Firestore in Datastore Mode. The error did not happen before the automatic migration from Datastore to Firestore in Datastore Mode.

Besides any ideas how I could avoid using the mentioned anti-pattern,

how is it possible that the projection-query works and the keys-only-query not? I would assume that internally they happen to be almost the same.

Best
Stefan